# Which is the missing number?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, pattern

I am working on this puzzle since last week.

```
01 ?? 05 12

10 13 15 09

14 02 08 03

04 07 11 06
```

which is the missing number **??**

note : answer is not 16

Comment: Hi, could you help to illustrate where this puzzle question comes from or it's originated by someone?

Comment: @Conifers it was asked to me at **wipro** company interview

Comment: yes 00 and 16 makes sense but we need to find more theoritical logic...

Comment: @babasaheb I answered your question with proper explaination and theory...

Answer (score 3):

A valid answer is

> `00`

Explanation:

> The existing numbers in the 4x4 matrix range from 1 through 15. From my perspective, there seem to be no logical coherence in their placement. Hence the remaining possible number in the sequence is either one more than the last number, `16`, or one less than the first number `00`. As 16 is ruled out in the question, 00 is the remaining option.

---

Credits to @SayedMohdAli for discussing this in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
01  -01  5   7

10   13  15  9

14   2   8   3

4    7   11  6
```

The sum of the numbers on the outside is twice the sum of the numbers inside: 76, 38